# "ImportError: No module named runner" while running "Parallel Library" in Robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

## STEP 1: I am trying to use following parallel library in robot framework:

https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/browse/proto/parallel/Parallel.py?r=86ca36b0d6dfacb3947d7988a447cadb5e873d75

## STEP 2 : My Robot Testsuite is :

```
***Settings***

Library         Telnet
Documentation     A Test suite to be ran in parallel
Library           Parallel    Suite    ${DATA_LIST}

*** Variables ***

${HOST1}                1.1.1.1
${HOST2}                1.1.1.2
${USERNAME}             admin
${PASSWORD}             test

***Test Cases***

testcase1

    Open Connection         ${HOST1}
    Login   ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
    Write                   enable
    Write                   upgrade tftp://10.1.1.1/image.img
    Open Connection         ${HOST2}
    Login   ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
    Write                   enable
    Write                   upgrade tftp://10.1.1.1/image.img
```

## STEP 3: When running the above testsuite I got following error:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project>pybot "Qn to ask.txt"
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project\
Qn to ask.txt': Importing test library 'Parallel' failed: ImportError: No module
 named runner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Parallel.py", line 24, in <module>
    import robot.runner as runner
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.7.5-py2.7.egg
  C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
  C:\Python27\DLLs
  C:\Python27\lib
  C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
  C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
  C:\Python27
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
  .
  C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project
==============================================================================
Qn to ask :: A Test suite to be ran in parallel
==============================================================================
testcase1                                                             | FAIL |
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine acti
vely refused it
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Qn to ask :: A Test suite to be ran in parallel                       | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project\report.html

C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project>
```

## STEP 4 : Then I installed the runner package as shown below:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project>pip install runner
Downloading/unpacking runner
  Downloading Runner-1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\test\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_test\runner\
setup.py) egg_info for package runner

Installing collected packages: runner
  Running setup.py install for runner

Successfully installed runner
Cleaning up...
C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project>
```

## STEP 5: But still I am getting "ImportError: No module named runner" as shown below:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project>pybot "Qn to ask.txt"
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project\
Qn to ask.txt': Importing test library 'Parallel' failed: ImportError: No module
 named runner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Parallel.py", line 24, in <module>
    import robot.runner as runner
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.7.5-py2.7.egg
  C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
  C:\Python27\DLLs
  C:\Python27\lib
  C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
  C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
  C:\Python27
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
  .
  C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project
==============================================================================
Qn to ask :: A Test suite to be ran in parallel
==============================================================================
testcase1                                                             | FAIL |
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine acti
vely refused it
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Qn to ask :: A Test suite to be ran in parallel                       | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project\report.html

C:\Users\test\Desktop\RFW - Parallel Execution Project>
```

Any clue please?

PS : "error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" is due to my connection problem. Please ignore this. I am worried only about "ImportError: No module named runner".

Comment: Does it work when you run `import robot` or `import robot.runner` manually from Python interpreter? Is that `robot` module in your Python path? When solving import errors you basically need to know where it is, where Python thinks it is and whether both matches. Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: @Messa "import robot" executed successfully in python interpreter. But I am getting same error with "import robot.runner". I think yes,  "robot" module is in my python path, because PYTHONPATH "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries" line shows this. Is this correct?

Comment: The file proto/parallel/Parallel.py you are linking is 4 years old. There was robot.runner back then: https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/browse/src/robot/runner.py?r=86ca36b0d6dfacb3947d7988a447cadb5e873d75 But it is not now: https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/browse/?r=70b63d951a8b2eefb53c67ccb60af6b5886c8d1e#hg%2Fsrc%2Frobot

Comment: It looks that `robot.runner` has been just renamed to `robot.run`. But there may be more changes than that.

Comment: Also the runner (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Runner) you have installed with `pip install runner` looks completely unrelated to Robot Framework or to your problem.

Comment: @Messa I am unable to find "Parallel.py" in the link you mentioned "https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/browse/?r=70b63d951a8b2eefb53c67ccb60af6b5886c8d1e#hg%2Fsrc%2Frobot". Could you please tell me, how to use this?

Comment: It's here: https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/source/browse/proto/parallel/Parallel.py?r=70b63d951a8b2eefb53c67ccb60af6b5886c8d1e

Comment: @Messa Thanks so much for your help. Its working with the file that you provided. Thanks a lot.